# Can't access to middle table in LINQ with entity framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble doing a query in LINQ. It's a very simple one in SQL.

Here are my tables:

[image: database diagram]

Here is the query I want to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE IDRecipe IN ( 
                    SELECT IDRecipe FROM RecipeTag 
                        INNER JOIN Tag ON Tag.IDTag = RecipeTag.IDTag  
                    WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%')
```

Here is what I tried, but the problem is that strangely, the table RecipeTag doesn't exist in the context. It's seems to be in the Recipe but when I do db.Recipes.RecipeTag it doesn't exist...

```
var recipeTag = from rt in db.RecipeTag
                join tg in db.Tags on rt.IDTag equals tg.IDTag
                where tg.Name.Contains(str)
                select rt.IDRecipe;

IEnumerable<Recipe> recipesTemp3 = (from recipe in db.Recipes
                                    where recipeTag.Contains(recipe.IDRecipe)
                                    select recipe).ToList();
```

I'm totaly new to LINQ so sorry if it's a very basic question but I can't find anywhere answers for this!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ turns many-to-many relationships into collection properties on each outer table.
You don't need the middle table at all.

Instead,

```
from recipe in db.Recipes
where recipe.RecipeTags.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(str))
select recipe
```

Or, more simply:

```
from tag in db.RecipeTags
where tag.Name.Contains(str)
from recipe in tag.Recipes
select recipe
```

Comment: Not sure the "more simply" version is simpler... :-)

Comment: I agree with @Joce, the first one is way simpler!! That did the trick and now I understand a little bit better! Thanks

Comment: yeah sorry for de delay, I tried right after my comment but it was too soon (needed to wait for x minutes)

Answer (score 0):

```
var recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r=>r.RecipeTag.Any(t=>t.Tag.Name.Contains("whatever")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want:

```
var recipeTags = db.RecipeTags.Where(p => p.Tag.Name.Contains(str)).Select(p => p.Recipe).ToList();
```

Comment: That won't compile; `Recipes` is a collection

Comment: Surely each RecipeTag entity has one instance of a Recipe assigned to it?

Comment: No; there can be more than one recipe in a tag.